# Accessing Postgresql server given link

Tags: postgresql, backend

I have a back end development task where I am required to access a postgresql server and retrieve some reports. In the specification this is how it's stated

" You have two abstract reports made available to you on a PostgreSQL server located at:
postgres://aaaaaaaaaa.bbbbb.org/ccccc "

(I have censored the link because it contains the company name)

Basically I have no idea what to do with this link as I've never seen anything like it before. It doesn't work in a browser because it's not http. I have looked online and at other questions here on stackoverflow but I've seen nothing similar. Could it also be some form of typo?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't looked very hard. Google "postgresql connection url".

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING

or it could be part of a JDBC connection string

https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html

I'm assuming you've made a mistake in your question and it's "postgresql:" not "postgres:".

Comment: Ah I see. I'm still new to this and I was searching in the wrong direction. Thanks for the help